# Is that correct `vim -S session` will load `.vimrc` again?

Tags: vim

I found out all the settings in `.vimrc` actually are stored in `session` file. If that is the case, why `vim -S session` load `.vimrc` again? Why does vim design like this?

I have some commands in `.vimrc` and when I use `vim -S`, it causes problems because those commands should only be run once, not twice.

Thanks a lot.

My problematic vimrc block in `mksession`:

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
augroup ProjectDrawer
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
  autocmd TabNew * call feedkeys(":Vexplore\<CR>", 'n')
augroup END
```

Answer (score 4):

#### What a session stores

What gets stored in a saved session is controlled by the [`:help 'sessionoptions'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27) option. It's defaults are very conservative, aimed at not losing any ad-hoc mappings or changed options.

However, most users place their settings in the `~/.vimrc`, use plugins and filetype plugins, and generally do not make up mappings or change settings on the fly. If that kind of workflow also applies to you, I'd suggest to remove the following values:

```
:set sessionoptions-=globals
:set sessionoptions-=localoptions
:set sessionoptions-=options
```

You may also want to remove `buffers` and `resize`, too. That change not just reduces the size of the saved session, it also prevents that an old session overrides any configuration that you've changed in your `~/.vimrc` in the meantime.

#### vimrc reload

So, your `~/.vimrc` isn't directly reloaded, but (with default `'sessionoptions'`), a lot of options and variables are restored.

By using `:augroup` followed by `:autocmd!`, you've also avoided a frequent beginner's mistake: Without that, the autocmds would be redefined on each reload of your `~/.vimrc`. The `:autocmd!` prevents that, and the `:augroup` makes that apply just to your own group.

#### sessions and special (plugin) buffers

A session should store all currently open buffers. Regular buffers contain file contents, and these can easily be reloaded when a session is opened again. Unfortunately, plugins (mis-)use buffers for their user interfaces (e.g. a sidebar, as by the *netrw* plugin), and Vim's session handling is not clever enough to distinguish between the two. But those plugin buffers have no corresponding file; instead, the plugin used command to directly build and modify its contents, often with the help of plugin variables that - see above - either are or aren't saved and restored.

Plugins would have to explicitly handle session restoration; I don't remember any plugin that does this, though. So often, you'll see an "empty" window restored, and the plugin may or may not recognize or reuse that. (And I think that's the problem you're asking about.)

The general recommendation is to **close any plugin buffers before saving a session**, either manually, or by writing a custom `:Mksession` wrapper that automates this for you. On session reload, your configuration may then create a fresh, functional plugin window again. (Or you have to trigger that manually.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation. But I still don't quite understand what to do to fix the problem. I have put the problematic .vimrc block in the question. Can you please show me what to do to make it work? With the problematic .vimrc block, there are two problems: (1) :mksession does remember the Explore window, but when I use -S session, the Explore window can not be restored, instead, it just shows an empty window. (2) Even if I use `augroup` and `autocmd!`, -S session still opened a new sidebar. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I think I finally understand what the issue is for you. Unfortunately, there's no good solution, only a workaround; see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Not all the settings from the vimrc are stored in the session file (see `:h mksession`). The settings you see are specified in the `:h sessionoptions` option.

You can load a session without loading the vimrc by using `vim -u NORC -S`; however, you'll quickly see you're missing your desired baseline settings.

Which commands should only be run once? There are specific ways to prevent commands from running twice unnecessarily when sourcing your vimrc.

For instance, if the command that should only be run once is an `autocmd` you should use an `augroup` like so:

```
augroup vimrc
  autocmd!  " Remove all vimrc autocommands
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html so <sfile>:h/html.vim
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually, I figured out I have two problems right now. (1) The command I want to avoid is `autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore`. (2) I found out the `:mksession` does remember there was a split window, but `vim -S` just opens an empty sidebar to me instead of the :Explore window.

Comment: Exactly. An `autocmd` should not run twice. So you need to use an `augroup` with the `autocmd!` exclamation point. See my edits.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the problematic block I have in my .vimrc. It just doesn't work at all when I use `mksession`. I am not sure how to fix it.. Actually, it's wrapped with `augroup`. Thanks.